# Testing snack bar in android testing when using jetpack compose

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-snackbar

I'm using jetpack compose and use this code to show my Snackbar:

```
 LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.snackBar.collectLatest { message ->
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = message)
        }
    }
```

Normally, when I want to access to a compose element, I use the `testTag` in `modifier`. But the Snackbar does not have any. So how can I test that my Snackbar is shown with specific text?

I tried to use:

```
 composeRule.onNodeWithText(SNACKBAR_MESSAGE).assertIsDisplayed()
```

but it can't find any node.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and ultimately resorted to the following in order to get my test to pass:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(
    hasText(SNACKBAR_MESSAGE),
    useUnmergedTree = true
).assertIsDisplayed()
```

What was of critical importance was including `useUnmergedTree = true`

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the testtag in snackbar modifier and we can assert it.

```
Snackbar(
      modifier = Modifier
                  .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                  .testtag("Snackbar"))
         { 
            Text(text=label,modifider=Modifier.testtag("SnackBar_Text")
          }
```

Testing Code

```
onNodeWithTag("Snackbar").assertIsDisplayed
onNodeWithTag("SnackBar_Text").assertIsDisplayed //can get text from config and assert the strings too
```

Comment: Hi @naggab, are you using the same snackbar component where the testtag added? it's working fine for me